# Errors using Conda

Tags: conda, anaconda

When try to update Cython from Conda using `conda install -c anaconda cython=0.24` I get the following error:

```
Error: Missing write permissions in: /home/user/anaconda3
#
# You don't appear to have the necessary permissions to install packages
# into the install area '/home/user/anaconda3'.
# However you can clone this environment into your home directory and
# then make changes to it.
# This may be done using the command:
#
# $ conda create -n my_root --clone=/home/user/anaconda3
```

And when I try `sudo conda install -c anaconda cython=0.24` I get a `sudo: conda: command not found` error.

Answer (score 1):

I just changed the user from root to user for /home/user/anaconda3 and things are working.

This command wont work `sudo conda install -c anaconda cython=0.24` as
 `sudo conda` is not a valid command . One should ensure that anaconda has correct user and permission when it is installed.